# What proofs are there of this result (on square roots and continued fractions)?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, continued-fractions

$ \sqrt{a^2+b} =  a+\cfrac{b}{2a+\cfrac{b}{2a+\cfrac{b}{2a+\dots}}}$

For example $\sqrt{7} \approx 2.64575$
Here we have :

$\sqrt{2^2+3} = 2+\cfrac{3}{4+\cfrac{3}{4+\cfrac{3}{4+\dots}}}$

According to the book Continued Fractions By C. D. Olds [Continued Fractions](https://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Esohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf), this result would have been first discovered by Rafael Bombelli in his 1752 treaty on algebra.

Comment: Hint: what is the solution of $x=a+\dfrac b{a+x}$ for $x>0$ ?

Comment: To follow Raymond's comment it is first necessary to show the continued fraction is convergent. If you care about that kind of thing. Contradictions can arise otherwise

Comment: At the bottom , we also have an equality , not just an approximation , unless we truncate the continued fraction somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Raymond Manzoni's comment I understand now,
for $x >0$

$x = a + \frac{b}{a+x} \iff x^2 = a^2 + b$ and so we have $x = \sqrt{a^2+b}$